# Is it possible keep an NSTask running even after app terminates?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am using `NSTask` to download/upload files to a server. When I quit the app, the download/upload also stops. Is there any way to keep these tasks running after the app quits?

In general, I want to implement the feature like Safari downloads, which continue after Safari terminates.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a background-app / background **service**-app / **deamon** which will take the control once you start upload or downloading of your files.